# Git on user home directory: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Tags: git, macos

It seems Git is broken on my `Users/username' directory. I got this 'fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git' all the time when I open terminal. It will not affect my git project but really annoying.

How could I fix this error message on user home directory?[image]

Comment: You've added a command to your bashrc that calls git. Remove that command.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked on `.zshrc`, it has one line `plugins=(git)` which related with git, I delete it. However I still get this issue.